# VirtualBox or Docker for shared software development environment?

Tags: virtualbox, docker, development

I am very conversant with VirtualBox, but someone has told me "oh, you should use Docker" and we can't seem to communicate enough to make me understand why.

Basically, I want to share a software development environment with a friend, so that we can be certain that we have identical IDEs, packages, plugins/extensions, etc; the only difference will be the code that we are each currently working on, and that gets in & out thorough Git.

I hope that we can use only VS Code as IDE, although there will be both PHP sever-side and Flutter/Dart client-side and my friend is conversant with Android Studio and would prefer to use that for client-side.

I would *strongly* prefer to use a single IDE (VS Code) and hope to sway him. Although, might turn out to be two VS Code installations, one with front-end and one with back-end extensions. I am not asking for help on that decision, just trying to point out what might be in our VM.

We will also need an Apache server, and probably Libre Office for documentation.

What little I know of Docker leads me to believe that it would be smaller, but I *think* that it tends more to single app.

If it were VirtualBox, I would just install Ubuntu and `apt get install` a few apps. With Docker, I don't know where to start, although I am sure that YouTube would be informative.

So, I imagine that my questions are can/should I use Docker for this, and what advantages would it have?

Comment: If it turns out you need two different VS Code installation, why bother with packaging them into the common development environment if they aren't common? Re. _"I think that [Docker] tends more to single app"_ - yes, but you can run multiple Docker containers, each hosting a single service, that will communicate with each other. The advantage of Docker is that you don't have to virtualize hardware and OS, so it's much more lightweight. On Linux hosts at least, because on other hosts you have to* run Linux in a VM anyway to host Linux containers.

Comment: (* You can run Windows-native Docker containers directly on bare metal I believe, but since you're mentioning `apt` I'm assuming that you'd prefer to use Linux containers)

Comment: Recommend to watch some docker tutorial, these questions should be mentioned in most tutorials earlier part. Live and learn. it's always good to touch new technology. :)

Comment: Yup, I am working my way through Max S's Docker course right now & It looks like that is the way to go, with multiple Docker containers, as it seems to be easy to deploy a Docker container to production, but not a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are to setup a new environment and share this with someone else, or otherwise provide access to it, correct?

You have experience with Oracle VirtualBox, but a friend recommended Docker.

If your goal is to share this VM instance with the other person so they work inside that instance locally, then the reason they suggest Docker is likely because that is what they are using. Docker uses Microsoft Hyper-V and if you use Oracle VirtualBox, you cannot use Hyper-V or Docker at the same time too which means that if they already use Docker, they would no longer be able to do that.

If you allow them access to your services remotely, then it doesn't matter for them, only your way to setup access matters, but that would probably make development slower for them.

You can of course use Hyper-V and share the VHDX file with them to achieve the same goal, but have a Virtual Machine.

I do share your concern about Docker being more for one application rather than grouping multiple apps. Docker seems to be hosting a service and interact with it remotely rather than using it as a service to connect to.

My answer would therefor be, stick with what you know, and if they request Docker because they don't want to lose their ability to use docker, then consider using Hyper-V. This of course does mean that you no longer will be able to use VirtualBox yourself.

If that is not an option, then the best solution is to use VirtalBox, install everything, create multiple user accounts and install xrdp so they can connect to your server using Microsoft Remote Desktop and work off of your server directly.

Comment: You seem to be assuming Windows host, which is not necessarily true. Also I think Virtualbox can use Hyper-V as a backend in the newer versions.

Comment: I have just read elsewhere that a Docker container used for development can be deployed to a production server, which is not so easy with a traditional VM